# Redis maxmemory-policy noeviction but keys disappear without error

Tags: redis

I use redis in docker with `image: redis:5.0.3` and time to time I faced with all keys was despirred. I try to figure out what is going on. First checked `maxmemory-policy` and `maxmemory` looks like correct, but maybe `noeviction` should be on a top ?

```
127.0.0.1:6379>  config get maxmemory-policy
1) "maxmemory-policy"
2) "noeviction"
127.0.0.1:6379>  config get maxmemory
1) "maxmemory"
2) "0"
```

then checked my `redis_server.conf`, looks like correct `maxmemory-policy noeviction`

```
root@ec59084b3d77:/data# cat /etc/redis-server/redis_server.conf 
# General
port 6379
bind 0.0.0.0
#dir /var/lib/redis
timeout 0
tcp-keepalive 20
tcp-backlog 10000
loglevel notice
logfile ""
databases 16

# Snapshotting
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
dbfilename dump.rdb

# Replication
slave-serve-stale-data yes
slave-read-only yes
repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
slave-priority 100
min-slaves-max-lag 10
# Security
# Limits
maxclients 30000
maxmemory-policy noeviction

# Append Only Mode
appendonly no
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appendfsync everysec
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb

# Lua
lua-time-limit 5000

# Slow Log
slowlog-log-slower-than 10000
slowlog-max-len 128

# Event Notification
notify-keyspace-events ""

# Advanced
hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64
list-max-ziplist-entries 512
list-max-ziplist-value 64
set-max-intset-entries 512
zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64
activerehashing yes
client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit slave 256mb 64mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
hz 10
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
```

But time to time my keys disappear, yesterday I had 7514 keys but today I found only 76. I checked it executed `keys *` or `dbsize`.

Could you help me, check please my redis config.

the same cased when I use `image: redis:alpine`. The same result in maxmemory-policy and maxmemory. I thought I should faced with error about allow memory size when keys spent all memory, but no, just disappear keys.

Answer (score 2):

Your `redis.conf` looks fine, the commands you are executing about the memory and evictions also show that.

The redis [documentation](https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache#eviction-policies) says that

> **noeviction** return errors when the memory limit was reached and the client is trying to execute commands that could result in more memory to be used (most write commands, but DEL and a few more exceptions).

So if you have n applications talking to this redis of which's `maxmemory` set to `zero` and `eviction policy` is `noeviction` then when you exceed the limit, those applications will throw exceptions. If you are not getting any `OOM` error/exception, then my optimist guess is that it is not related to the `eviction`.

Here are the possible problems and debugging solutions i may suggest;

There is a drastic drop from 7514 to 74. I think it could;

- Expire policies on the keys

  - Please be sure that there is no "strong" expire policy on those keys.
- Redis server is restarting itself.

  - You may check Redis logs to see is there any related logs about `restart`/`shutdown` activities.
- One or more applications/clients are executing `flushall`/`flushdb`.

  - You may execute [SLOWLOG](https://redis.io/commands/slowlog) to see if there is any flush commands.
  - If key disappearance happens regularly, you may try to [monitor](https://redis.io/commands/monitor) it for a while (grep/write into a log file and search inside it, you will see the ip address of the client executing the command).
  - You may [disable](https://redis.io/topics/security#disabling-of-specific-commands) `flushall`/`flushdb` methods from redis.conf and keep checking is there any key loss after it.
- If you don't have `password`, maybe you may set and update your clients and see if it happens again.
- Heavy delete operation on some keys

  - You may use [keyspace notifications](https://redis.io/topics/notifications) too any key deletion commands are executed.

Comment: I put a bounty on this question because I had the same symptoms, but it turned out that was because of buggy code that did SWAPDB with another db way more times that it should have (only 1 at the end of an import actually). Might be worth checking if there are other dbs too.

Comment: @greg0ire i saw it after the bounty, these were the steps that we tried to find the root cause, it showed that one of the libraries’ command was flushing it.

Comment: I will probably award the bounty to you, but it would be great to hear from OP first. The post is quite recent, they might still have the issue.

Comment: @greg0ire you are totally right, also key deletion reasons are different from each other, would like to know what is op’s case.

Comment: No answer… here is the bounty, congrats!