# redis removes key before expire time and memory limit

Tags: redis

I've installed redis in CentOS7 with

```
yum install redis
```

I used redis-cli to check current memory, but redis was using only 0.1% of allocated memory.

```
# Memory
used_memory:1068640
used_memory_human:1.02M
maxmemory:1000000000
maxmemory_human:953.67M
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
```

Keys are inserted every 1 minute, about 3kb.

And I'm inserting data in python redis module.

```
redis_connection.set(key, value, timedelta(days=2))
```

The keys/values are inserted well, but redis removes key before 2 days.

`ttl <key> command` shows me `172797`(about 2 days)

What configuration do I have to change to prevent removing keys before expire time?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/62584515/2188922 may give some ideas/insights about it.

Comment: I've changed noeviction to volatile-ttl and appendonly to yes. Now I'm monitoring redis removes key or not.

Comment: I found "flushall" command executed from unknown program.. But it have same ip address and different port.

Comment: Maybe some other program in the same server is executing it or a framework which has some background process.

Comment: I hope your Redis instance isn't runing on public Internet. If so, it might be intruded and hijacked. (It's pretty common)

Comment: After changing flushall to other. Than flushall doesn't appear anymore. This is only a test server, but I have to be careful. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

After monitoring in `redis-cli monitor`, I've found that someone is sending "FLUSHALL" commands.

So, I changed my redis port(default 6379 -> other) and added  `rename-command FLUSHALL <rename_flushall>` and it worked.